# How do I get my code to work for large values of N?

Tags: c++, c++14

The input consists of a string followed by N. The string consists of at most 30 uppercase characters, and N≤10<sup>18</sup>. The code outputs the Nth character of the infinite code built from the initial string. The first character is N=1.

The last character of the string is moved to the first position and then the resulting string is appended to the previous string in each iteration.

SAMPLE INPUT:

```
COW 8
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
C
```

In this example, the initial string COW expands as follows:

```
COW -> COWWCO -> COWWCOOCOWWC

                 12345678
```

The problem is that for large values of N eg.10<sup>7</sup>, the code crashes. Can anyone please suggest methods to remove the error.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

char sCowCode(string str, long long int N){

    long long int a = str.length();

    if(N < a){
        return str[N-1];
    }

    while(2*a < N + 1)
        a *= 2;

    if(a == N)
        return sCowCode(str, a-1);

    return sCowCode(str, N - a -1);
}



int main(){

    long long int N;
    string str;

    cin >> str;
    cin >> N;


    char a = sCowCode(str, N);

    cout<<a<<endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the string contain whitespaces? In that case `cin >> str;` doesn't work

Comment: No, it does not contain any white spaces

Comment: What "error" do you get? My guess is that your code simply crashes because of too deep recursion.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Sample Input and Output provided.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: You'll probably need to transform your recursive algorithm into a looping algorithm.

Comment: @FredLarson This code doesn't appear to be building any large strings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know the problems with using namespac std and <bits/stdc++.h>. But I am currently practicing for a programming competition where I would want to save as much time writing dependencies as much I can.

Comment: I don't understand the transition `COWWCO -> COWWCOOCOWWC` in your example. How did the second half, `OCOWWC`, come about?

Comment: @aschepler: Oh, I misunderstood. I thought N was the string size.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The string is rotated right, then appended to itself. Then THAT string is rotated right and appended to itself. Took me a minute, too.

Comment: @ShubhamRaj -- *I am currently practicing for a programming competiton…* -- Note the forum you are posting to.  There is no competition here.  Post clear, readable, non-obfuscated code.  You are not racing someone when posting code here.

Comment: Any writing of code builds habits. And if you do a lot of online judge/competition site work you use a lot of bad habits. And like any habit, good as bad, it tend to stick. So please use good habits from the very beginning. It doesn't save that much time to use bad habits in the long run. And good habits will be better in the long run, especially when you want to apply for work. And more importantly, don't use such sites as a learning resource, because they're *not*.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry for the bad code format. I am new to this forum and C++ as a whole so might take time getting used to.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I edited the question to explain how the iteration works.

Comment: `sCowCode` is a perfect candidate for tail call optimization, but who knows exactly how those online judge sites compile? I agree with @FrançoisAndrieux: avoid recursion.

Comment: @ShubhamRaj -- Ok.  No problem.  However when posting on SO, it would be good if 1) You have a local compiler to test with instead of the online compiler, 2) You take the time to format the code in a presentable manner -- again, you're not racing here  3) Place known input directly in the program code instead of `cin` or `scanf` statements.

Comment: Your recursive function is actually already close to tail recursive (what should make a rewriting as loop quite easier). For this, I would rewrite the last lines as `return sCowCode(str, N == a ? a - 1 : N - a -1);`. With a bit luck, the compiler recognizes/optimizes the tail-recursion on its own and you're done.

Comment: That I didn't see it earlier! You never change `str` but you pass it by value. Change this to a `const` reference: `sCowCode(const string &str, long long int N)`. With this change, g++ 9.3 will compile the recursive calls as loop - and even without changing the last lines as recommended in my previous comment. [**Demo on Compiler Explorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PKXFV2) FYI: [Tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

Comment: @Scheff That worked, thanks. And thanks for the help to everyone.